# Instagram IPHONE HOOKS - the app isnt opening

Tags: iphone, webview, instagram

Im trying to open Instagram from my own application, trying to get a list of photos tagged with "brazil". But Instagram isnt opening. Please see code snippet here.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    //Load URL
    NSURL *instagramURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"instagram://tag?name=brazil"];
   if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:instagramURL]) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:instagramURL];
   }

    NSURLRequest *instagramRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:instagramURL];

    [instagramWebView loadRequest:instagramRequest];
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Forgive the obvious question, but I assume you're testing on device, not the simulator? And I'm not sure why you're trying to subsequently open the URL in a webview?

Comment: Yes tried on device. No thats true about the webview. Will delete it and try again.

Comment: Ok, now it works. Do you know any solution how I can redirect back to my own app from Instagram after?